# C# - There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Role' of 'MainMenuForm.MainMenuForm(string)'

Tags: c#, sql, authentication, arguments

Good evening,

I am trying to create a role based login for my C# WinForms App. I am still a very basic C# user, and this is part of an academic project. The error above is showing, and I'm not sure how to tackle it.

The logins are taken from a local DB I have created, connected to the .NET (for this application).

I have two users, one is Admin user, one is default user.

PLEASE NOTE, I know about the SQL Injection issue, I will sort that out as soon as I fix this error.

Can you kindly advise on how to fix this error, please?

Thank you in advance.

I was following a YT tutorial, and got as far as this part, where the error is generated - please see code below.

```
namespace Library_System_Project
{
    public partial class MainMenuForm : Form
    {
        public MainMenuForm(string Role) // Error occurs here
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lblRole.Text = Role; // Error occurs here
        }
```

---

Also, the below is on a different form, but related to the above:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Database Connection Setup
    SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Library System Project.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");
    string query = "Select * from Users where User_Username = '" + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + "' and User_Password = '" + txtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, Connection);
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    SDA.Fill(DT);

    // Access to Main Menu for Authorized Users
    if (DT.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        MainMenuForm MainMenu = new MainMenuForm(DT.Rows[0][0].ToString());
        MainMenu.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Winforms requires a parameterless constructor on its controls. Use property-injection instead.

Comment: Thanks Lennart. Apologies for being demanding, but can I ask to implement what you suggested in the code above, or maybe give me a simple example that I can follow so I can change it, please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, Winforms requires controls to have a parameterless constructor. You can work around that by creating a method to further initialize the Form:

```
public partial class MainMenuForm : Form
{
   public MainMenuForm()
   {
      InitializeComponent();            
   }

   public void SetRole(string role)
   {
       lblRole.Text = role;
   }
}
```

and then

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...

    // Access to Main Menu for Authorized Users
    if (DT.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        MainMenuForm MainMenu = new MainMenuForm();
        MainMenu.SetRole(DT.Rows[0][0].ToString());
        MainMenu.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Lennart, thanks for the help, however, I'm encountering a slight issue.

I have changed everything as needed on both MainMenuForm (SetRole) and the WelcomeForm (Ok button click). There is an extra code I have implemented yesterday, it may be causing the issue. When I log in as the admin, the functions are available, but when I navigate further on the app and revert back to the MainMenuForm, I lose the permission that an admin should have (UserMenu Function) - I have two users, one admin with Username 'jHarrington' and one default user with Username 'pDinklage' - please see below code

Comment: private void MainMenuForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((Form)this).Controls["lblRole"].Text != "jHarrington")
            {
                btnUserMenu.Enabled = false;
            }
        }